# How to create xml Document using result of XPath

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I'm reading xml document using XPath and I need to create a Document object using the result of XPath evaluation. Can some one tell me how to do this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create XML document using nodeList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786936/create-xml-document-using-nodelist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your xpath returns a single node, you can do something like:

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
doc.appendChild(doc.importNode(xpathResult, true));
```

If it returns a node set, you will have to create a root element yourself.

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
doc.appendChild(doc.createElement("root"));
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(doc.importNode(node, true));
}
```

Comment: Actually it returns Node set. So this is not going to work for me. Is there a way to append Node List to the document.

Answer (score 0):

refer
[Create XML document using nodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786936/create-xml-document-using-nodelist)