# Create XML document using nodeList

Tags: java, xml, dom, backend, nodelist

I need to create a XML Document object using the NodeList. Can someone pls help me to do this. This is my Java code:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.*; 
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String exp = "/configs/markets";
        String path = "testConfig.xml";
        try {
            Document xmlDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(path);
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(exp);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList)
              xPathExpression.evaluate(xmlDocument,
                                       XPathConstants.NODESET);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

I want to have an XML file like this:

```
<configs>
    <markets>   
        <market>
            <name>Real</name>
        </market>
        <market>
            <name>play</name>
        </market>
    </markets>
</configs>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should do it like this:

- you create a new `org.w3c.dom.Document newXmlDoc` where you store the nodes in your `NodeList`,
- you create a new root element, and append it to `newXmlDoc`
- then, for each node `n` in your `NodeList`, you import `n` in `newXmlDoc`, and then you append `n` as a child of `root`

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String exp = "/configs/markets/market";
    String path = "src/a/testConfig.xml";
    try {
        Document xmlDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder().parse(path);

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(exp);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPathExpression.
                evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        Document newXmlDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        Element root = newXmlDocument.createElement("root");
        newXmlDocument.appendChild(root);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);
            Node copyNode = newXmlDocument.importNode(node, true);
            root.appendChild(copyNode);
        }

        printTree(newXmlDocument);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void printXmlDocument(Document document) {
    DOMImplementationLS domImplementationLS = 
        (DOMImplementationLS) document.getImplementation();
    LSSerializer lsSerializer = 
        domImplementationLS.createLSSerializer();
    String string = lsSerializer.writeToString(document);
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root><market>
            <name>Real</name>
        </market><market>
            <name>play</name>
        </market></root>
```

Some notes:

- I've changed `exp` to `/configs/markets/market`, because I suspect you want to copy the `market` elements, rather than the single `markets` element
- for the `printXmlDocument`, I've used the interesting code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219596/how-to-i-output-org-w3c-dom-element-to-string-format-in-java/1219806#1219806)

I hope this helps.

---

If you don't want to create a new root element, then you may use your original XPath expression, which returns a `NodeList` consisting of a single node (keep in mind that your XML must have a single root element) that you can directly add to your new XML document.

See following code, where I commented lines from the code above:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //String exp = "/configs/markets/market/";
    String exp = "/configs/markets";
    String path = "src/a/testConfig.xml";
    try {
        Document xmlDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder().parse(path);

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(exp);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPathExpression.
        evaluate(xmlDocument,XPathConstants.NODESET);

        Document newXmlDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        //Element root = newXmlDocument.createElement("root");
        //newXmlDocument.appendChild(root);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);
            Node copyNode = newXmlDocument.importNode(node, true);
            newXmlDocument.appendChild(copyNode);
            //root.appendChild(copyNode);
        }

        printXmlDocument(newXmlDocument);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will give you the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<markets>   
        <market>
            <name>Real</name>
        </market>
        <market>
            <name>play</name>
        </market>
    </markets>
```

Comment: it works fine Marco. But the problem is there is element called root which is not orginally in the xml document. Is there a way to do it without having the root element. Thanks in advance

Comment: well, you need a root element in an XML. What you might do is extract `markets` with your original XPath (`String exp = "/configs/markets";`), and then your `NodeList` will contain a single node, which can directly import and append to your new XML document: see edited answer.

Comment: @MarcoS Is there any way of retaining the all the ancestor nodes also, while copying/cloning an XML Node ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the `adoptNode()` method of [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#adoptNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29). 
Maybe you will need to iterate over your `NodeList`. You can access the individual `Nodes` with `nodeList.item(i)`.
If you want to wrap your search results in an `Element`, you can use createElement() from the `Document` and `appendChild()` on the newly created `Element`