# XPath processor output as string

Tags: java, xpath

Standard XPath processing in java with javax.xml.xpath works like this:

1. I provide name for xml to process
2. I provide xpath expression as a string.
3. I gain answer stored as a list of nodes, or eventually as a single value depending on what type of output I select.

I need to write a couple of tests in java which basically should work like this: 
I provide xpath expression as a string and it checks if xpath output of this expression equals to some specified output(also provided as string). So I dont need traversing through node tree and stuff, I just need to gain xpath processor output as a string. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`XPath.evaluate(expression, inputSource)` seems to do what you want.

Edit: Here's some sample code:

```
String xml = "<foo><bar>text</bar></foo>";
Reader reader = new StringReader(xml);
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(reader);
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
System.out.println(xpath.evaluate("/foo/bar", inputSource));
```

Edit: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300839/get-a-nodes-inner-xml-as-string-in-java-dom) indicates that there is no java api that can be instantly used to meet your goals. If you're testing XML, then you might want to have a look at [XmlUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: thanks, but this produces somehow "raw" output, for example for
"/foo/bar", output is "text" whereas shouldn't it be "<bar>text</bar>" ? I need full output with tags and stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
xPathExpression.evaluate(document);
```

where `document` is your DOM document, then it will return a string representation of the first node it matches.  That's probably fine for the use case where you believe that your XPath is selecting a single text node.  If that's not the case, you could write some `toString()` method for `NodeList` that is returned from:

```
xPathExpression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

EDIT 1: Here's a [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786936/create-xml-document-using-nodelist) article on converting a `NodeList` to an XML document and printing it.

EDIT 2: If you have XPath expressions that use `count` or logical operators that return single values, then you could catch the exception thrown and take the appropriate action:

```
try {
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPathExpression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
    }
} catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
    String result = xPathExpression.evaluate(document);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: yeah but sometimes Xpath output is not neccesary a node or node list, it can be also a boolean or integer value, I need a flexible way of gaining output no matter what kind of xpath expression it hadles.

Comment: If you ask if for a `NODESET` it will give you one, even if it's a list of one node with a boolean value or integer value.

Comment: Nope, when I do this "XPathException: Can not convert #NUMBER to a NodeList!" occurs

Comment: Post your XPath in your question.  This usually happens when you're using something like `count(/foo/bar)`.

Comment: when I don't pass any additional argument to evaluate() it returns string containing only first node that matches given expression(no all, which is bad). If I instead pass XPathConstants.NODESET to evaluate(), it works fine if query asks for list of texts, but for count(...) or logical queries it throws exception I posted above. I want code that do not depend of which of NODESET, NUMBER, or BOOLEAN I pass to evaluate()

Comment: XPath in any language will throw that exception if you're purposefully selecting a value instead of a set of nodes.  Either you pass in a flag to your method saying "This xPath is special" and take the appropriate action, or just try selecting a `NODESET` and catch the exception.  See the edit above.